# Detect cursor position in TWebBrowser at edit mode

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, ihtmldocument2

I get selection range like this:

```
var
  Range: IHTMLTxtRange;
begin
  if Supports((Document as IHTMLDocument2).selection.createRange,
    IHTMLTxtRange, Range)
end;
```

TWebBrowser in editing. I need get position of cursor. How I can get its?

Answer (score 1):

[IHTMLTxtRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872(VS.85).aspx) defines several attributes to get what you need.

But the key items are boundingLeft and boundingTop

[This link](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/topic53467.aspx) has some details on how it works as well.

Comment: I need find position cursor in characters from begin of string.Not coordinante in pixel.

Comment: Do you need visible characters or source characters?